# Authenticate user in a ms-access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication, ms-office

I have a MS-access database. But it is on the shared drive. And it is required that only some selected number of people can use it. Is there a way to authenticate the user?

Comment: @Varun--you may want to clarify.  Are you looking for security _within_ the DB or are you looking for security on the whole DB?  By the former, I'd mean someone can get in but they can't delete records or something of that sort.  The latter would be something like Knox's answer below.

Comment: It is security for the whole DB

Comment: @Varun--you probably want to edit your question to reflect that.  That's what I was saying. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Access is file driven, why not create a folder in the shared drive and assign folder permissions to the appropriate people.

Comment: Ensure that those who are allowed to use the database have full permissions and that those who are not allowed cannot open the database.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, open the database then run the Tools->Security->User-Level Security Wizard. It will step you through the process of creating a new workgroup file, creating users and groups, and securing the Access objects.

Comment: Does this stop a person from copying the actual file?  Knox's solution seems to cover that.

Comment: They can copy the file, but without the workgroup file and a valid account they're not getting in (well, not without a whole lot of work).

Comment: Jet user-level security is pretty easily cracked. That doesn't make it useless, but it means you shouldn't count on it to protect your data from copying. Use NTFS file permissions to control access to the MDB and Jet user-level security to control access within your application. Both are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Do both.** Set access permissions on the directory AND create a new security file for it.

The directory is your front-line security, and limits access on a macro level

The security file can be used to segment access to the various tables, forms, reports, etc. You can even us it give some people read only access and others more full permissions.

Answer (score 0):

User-level security is not available in Access 2007.

[Get started with Access 2007 security](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA101980471033.aspx) offers:

- Trust (enable) the disabled content
  in a database
- Use a password to
  encrypt or decrypt a database
- Package, sign, and deploy an Office
  Access 2007 database

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a domain could you not use file level security to prevent users from accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

I do all of this in VBA. In the switchboard Form_Open sub,  Read the user name into a string variable with a windows API, then check to see if the user name in on your list of valid users. If OK, issue a welcome message, if not OK exit Access.

' check user
    Dim user As String
    Dim AuthorizedUser As Boolean
    user = UCase(CurrentUser())

```
AuthorizedUser = True
Select Case user
    Case "USER_A":
    Case "USER_B":
    Case "USER_C":     
    Case Else: AuthorizedUser = False
End Select

If AuthorizedUser = True Then
   MsgBox "Welcome authorized user " & user
Else
   MsgBox user & "is not Authorized. For access to this database contact User_A"
   DoCmd.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Can't this just be circumvented by holding down shift while opening the database?

Comment: It could. Code lives in switchboard Form_Open sub, holding down the shift key disables opening the Switchboard when database opens. Not using this database for critical data, users have no experience with access, and only see compiled MDE file (no   visibility to VBA). Good comment, thanks.  --Mike

Comment: Yeah, @Mike basically it's a good preventative measure if your attacker isn't smart. I'm afraid that we shouldn't assume this. Yes, compiled MDE files don't have access to the VBA code, but as Leonard pointed out, they can just bypass the password and have full access to the linked databases or queries. Pretty quickly a select statement turns into a drop table statement.

Answer (score -2):

Two solutions:

1. Place the Access file on a file share with permissions set appropriately.  This doesn't work really well if you need to provide read-only access since Access can't write out the temporary .ldb file that it creates when opening an Access file (.mdb).
2. Move the "data" of the Access file to a Sql Server instance... where you can permissions in SQL server to restrict what people can do.  We use this method to provide readonly access to the everyone, and then specific people with read-write access.  To move the data to SQL you would import it into a new SQL database and then link the tables into the Access file (renaming so that reports/queries/etc continue to work).